# Color code in Bash using for loop in a Linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash

When I use color code separately in the `echo` statement, it works fine.

But I am trying to write 5 colored statements using for loop but it is not working.

What can I do?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in {31..35}
do
    echo -e "Normal \e[$imColoredText  \e[0m"
done
```

Output of individual code:

[image]

Output of Bash script:

[image]

Comment: `echo -e "Normal \e[${i}mColoredText  \e[0m"`

Comment: `man tput`. Rather than using echo, it's a lot cleaner to use `tput setaf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` and `printf` are both too fragile:

```
for i in {1..5}; do 
    echo Normal; tput setaf $i; echo ColoredText; tput setaf 9;
done
```

You can also do things like:

```
for i in {1..5}; do printf "Normal%sColoredText%s\n" "$(tput setaf $i)" "$(tput setaf 9)"; done
```

or:

```
red=$(tput setaf 1)
normal=$(tput setaf 9)
echo "${normal}Normal${red}Red${normal}"
```

Comment: `echo` is always too fragile because it works inconsistently between shell implementations, sometimes interpreting escaped characters, sometimes not, sometimes supporting flags, sometimes not.

Comment: `echo` with no flags is reliable, but probably should be purged from use.

Comment: `ash -c 'echo "hello\n"'` or `zsh -c 'echo "hello\n"'` prints two newlines after `hello`, but  `bash -c 'echo "hello\n"'` will print `hello\n` and a single newline. So, no, `echo` implementation is inconsistent between shells even with no flag. The only way to have a consistent `echo` implementation is to re-implement it as `echo(){ printf '%s\n' "$*";}`

Answer (score 1):

It is preferable not to use `echo -e` which is non-standard, but prefer `printf` instead.

Here it is:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

i=1
while [ $i -le 5 ]; do
  printf 'Normal '
  tput setaf "$i"
  printf 'ColoredText'
  tput sgr0
  printf '\n'
  i=$((i + 1))
done
```

Comment: Oh. Thanks I will remember

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your loop variable in curly brackets ([variable expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)):

`echo -e "Normal \e[${i}mColoredText  \e[0m"`